# TypeError: new Proxy target must be an Object

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I have expo project and i use tamagui. when i click checkbox, i got this error : TypeError: new Proxy target must be an Object. I did research but got no results.

My codes:

```
import { Check } from '@tamagui/lucide-icons'
import { Checkbox } from 'tamagui'

function MyCheckBox(){
    return(
        <Checkbox size="$4">
        <Checkbox.Indicator>
          <Check />
        </Checkbox.Indicator>
      </Checkbox>
    )
}

export default MyCheckBox;
```

App.tsx :

```
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { Paragraph, Spacer, TamaguiProvider, Theme, YStack } from "tamagui";
import  MyCheckBox  from "./components/CheckBox";
import config from "./tamagui.config";

export default function App() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    Inter: require("@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Medium.otf"),

    InterBold: require("@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Bold.otf"),
  });
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <TamaguiProvider config={config}>
      <Theme name={colorScheme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light"}>
        <YStack
          f={1}
          jc="center"
          ai="center"
          backgroundColor={"$backgroundSoft"}
        >
          <Paragraph color="$color" jc="center">
            {colorScheme}
          </Paragraph>
          <MyCheckBox/>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </YStack>
      </Theme>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  );
}
```

I added this to my code but no result :

```
const proxy = new Proxy(() => 0, { apply: () => 1 });
proxy()
```

I added CheckIcon my code but didn't work.